# Arbitrarily splitting an Address

Tags: formula, integration, validation, data, address

This is a bit of a weird one, but due to a limitation with the Bringg/Zenkraft integration, Shipments cannot be created if either address line 1 or address line 2 > 35 characters. The issue is that we do not always have control over how the address comes into SF since it comes from the web. At this time it the web team cannot change the inputs to match this sort of requirement.

My question is: can an address be split into address line 1 and address line 2 at any arbitrary point in the address? I know that typically we would put the street address on line 1, and then something like apartment number, suite, etc. on line 2. But if we have a case where an address has come in with > 35 characters on line 1, can we just split it on the 35th character and add in a new line character at that spot (going back a few indexes if necessary to not break a word)? Has anyone faced a similar requirement? How did you approach it?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). In theory, yes it is possible to split information into new fields but the out of the box address fields don't support more than one street field. You'd need to look at custom fields for this. We also don't have enough information in your question to understand how you're pushing this information into Salesforce which would help provide a more specific answer. Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: The OOTB xxxStreet field is a textarea field and can an arbitrary number of line breaks up to the length limit for the field (255). That said, I'd decouple the representation of addresses in SFDC that are designed for the UX with the bespoke requirements of your integration where the conversion should occur at runtime